# EF DataModel with Oracle Provider without installed ODAC components

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, odp.net

ASP.NET MVC, Entity Framework, DataModel.edmx with Oracle Provider, installed ODP.NET x86 Nugget Package.

Without ODAC components (from Oracle website) I get an error:

> Error 175: The specified store provider cannot be found in the
>   configuration, or is not valid

Why this error occurs ? ODP.NET x86 Nugget Package has been installed...

Answer (score 0):

See if this answer helps you out:
[Error 175: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021646/error-175-the-specified-store-provider-cannot-be-found-in-the-configuration-or)

Check for an extra copy of the  tag added to the machine.config. Make sure you are looking at the right machine.config too (32 bit)

Also, realize that a proper install of ODP.NET should add ODP.NET in this section of the machine.config. Since there is currently no official Oracle Nuget install I am not sure what exactly you installed.

Christian Shay

Oracle